# Affordable laptop with metal body for durability

Tags: laptop, pc

I need a laptop with the following requirements:

1. Keyboard must have a numberic keypad.
2. SSD or hybrid storage (small ssd+hdd).
3. Durable/sturdy body. Preferred metal alloy body.
4. Long battery life at least 8 hours.
5. Windows or no OS.
6. Intel 8th or 10th generation processor.
7. Good manufacturer support.
8. Good motherboard with no heating issue.
9. Maximum budget is USD900.

Comment: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic states... _Your question on Hardware Recommendations should:..._ Show previous research - Tell us what products you are aware of that do not meet your needs. Otherwise, you may get those products as recommendations, wasting your time and ours.